# Observer pattern suggestion

Tags: java, oop, jakarta-ee, design-patterns

I have three modules where user inserts some data  using application , it is basically a j2ee application where user just creates information there are three modules .At the end of insertion i have create a status in table of the data and send email notificaiton , this is common to all the three modules , would it be better to user  observer  pattern here.If not what would be better?-

Comment: Observer is used when you need to notify some parties about a change... I don't think that applies here...

Comment: to elaborate on what is said above... it notifies dependents when there is a change in state... The MVC pattern is based on the observer pattern only ... read more about it at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Comment: I am thinking of common code which will update status in db and send mail.All three modules will send notificaiton to this code and it will handle scenrio, still oberver wont fit?

Comment: better than what, and use the observer pattern to do what? What's the problem you're trying to solve and that isn't solved, or is badly solved by what you have now?

Comment: Does the email notification need to guarantee sent by other classes? If not, you need not to have observer pattern. You can just place the server call after the successful insert call back.

Comment: Strangly for me how does observer fit into MVC controller calls the view or model based on scenatio it is not notifying change in its state

Comment: Why not ? a simple button click is good example of observer. the state is changed from not pushed to pushed

Comment: Can you give  more explanatory example in web based  MVC

Comment: @ChrisSo how does it matter if need guarantee from email , please explain

Comment: The observer pattern is used in MVC in order to listen for changes to the model and update the view correspondingly.  So if you destroy the view after the customer submits their information then there is no need for it (the view is not dynamic).  But, if you want the view to update based on changes you made to the status table, then that is traditionally done using the observer pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Better use one of the below approaches generally used for your case

1. You can use Database triggers :
   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html
2. If you are using hibernate and don't want to implement functionality
       at database level, use hibernate interceptors :
       http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-interceptor-example-audit-log/