# Audit Log In portal

Tags: jsf, design-patterns, portlet, websphere-portal

I have already asked similar quesiton [Observer pattern suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806197/observer-pattern-suggestion)  ,I have to implement a audit log for portal where i have make an entry in DB about the feature user is accessign it can go lot dipper in short most of action of user has to be audited basically captured in DB.

I came across portlet filter , can anybody suggested if this can be interceptor kinf of concept for portal or portlert filter.

I am using websphere portal , jsr286 and jsf1.2

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a Portlet Filter should suit your requirement. You can create a single filter and access the Portal state information from the request to gather what kind of a request was made. This way you can apply the same filter across all your Portlets, but record what kind of a request was made in each case.

Remember you need to configure the filter for each Portlet, and apply it to specific life cycle phases. See: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Fcport_portlet_filters.html